# jQuery - Each checkbox toggles it's own menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to `open` / `close` each `menu` by `checking` / `unchecking` the corresponding `checkboxes`.

How do I show the menu when any of the checkboxes are checked? Right now the code is showing one at a time and isn't depending on the checkbox selection.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="menus"]').change(function() {
    const id = $(this).prop("id");
    $(".menu").each(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("active", $(this).data("id") == id);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.menus div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px
}

.menu {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.first {
  background: blue
}

.second {
  background: green
}

.third {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus" id="first">First
</label>
  <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus" id="second">Second
</label>
  <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus" id="third">Third
</label>
</div>
<div class="menus">
  <div class="menu first" data-id="first"></div>
  <div class="menu second " data-id="second"></div>
  <div class="menu third" data-id="third"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can make an attribute selector from the id and toggle the corresponding menu item that way and leave the others unchanged

```js
$('input[name="menus"]').change(function() {
  $(".menu[data-id=" + this.id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
});
```

```css
.menus div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px
}

.menu {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.first {
  background: blue
}

.second {
  background: green
}

.third {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus" id="first">First
</label>
  <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus" id="second">Second
</label>
  <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus" id="third">Third
</label>
</div>
<div class="menus">
  <div class="menu first" data-id="first"></div>
  <div class="menu second " data-id="second"></div>
  <div class="menu third" data-id="third"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I set the active class on the menu if the input is already checked? <input type="checkbox" name="menus" id="second" checked>

Comment: Can trigger the change on page load also... `$('input[name="menus"]').change(function() {
  /* change handling stuff*/
}).change();/* now trigger change*/`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="menus"]').change(function() {
    const id = $(this).prop("id");
    const checkboxStatus = $(this).is(":checked");
    $(".menu").each(function() {
      if ($(this).data("id") == id) {
        $(this).toggleClass("active", checkboxStatus);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.menus div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px
}

.menu {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.first {
  background: blue
}

.second {
  background: green
}

.third {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus" id="first">First
</label>
  <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus" id="second">Second
</label>
  <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus" id="third">Third
</label>
</div>
<div class="menus">
  <div class="menu first" data-id="first"></div>
  <div class="menu second " data-id="second"></div>
  <div class="menu third" data-id="third"></div>
</div>
```